# Update query for any number of columns and AND clauses

Tags: php, mysql

So I wrote this code to make a universal update query to handle any number of columns and "**AND**" clauses.

The code doesn't give any error and executes fine, however, in the all the columns it updates wrong value.

*My code updates all the columns with value of the last array key (in my example , the value of addedby is in all the columns when I run the script).*

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening, but couldn't reach to a conclusion. What wrong am I doing here?

My code :

```
    function update($arr,$warr,$table)
{
    global $conn;
    //first get the count of $arr and $warr
    $arrcount = count($arr);
    $warracount = count($warr);
    $arc=0; // $arr counter
    $warc =0; // $warc counter
    $updatestring = "UPDATE $table SET ";
    $wherestring = "WHERE ";
    //make the string now
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
        $arc++;
        $st = "$key=:$key";
        if($arc==$arrcount)
        {
            //this is the last one, a comma is not required
            $updatestring = $updatestring . $st;
        }
        else
        {
            $updatestring = $updatestring . $st . ",";
        }
    }

    foreach($warr as $wkey=>$wvalue)
    {
        $warc++;
        $st1 = "$wkey=:$wkey";
        if($warc==$warracount)
        {
            //this is the last, not need for AND
            $wherestring = $wherestring . $st1;
        }
        else
        {
            $wherestring = $wherestring . $st1 . " AND ";
        }
    }
    //now write the update query
    try
    {
        $s = $conn->prepare("$updatestring $wherestring");
        foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
        {
            $s->bindParam(":$key", $value);
        }
        foreach($warr as $wkey=>$wvalue)
        {
            $s->bindParam(":$wkey", $wvalue);
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    var_dump($s->execute());
}//function
$arr = array("firstname" => "Asas",
                     "lastname" => "Asas",
                     "location" => "Malmo",
                     "phone" => "Asas",
                     "email" => "Asas",
                     "linkedinprofile" => "Asasasas",
                     "employer" => "Asas",
                     "competencies" => "Asas",
                     "address" => "Asaasass",
                     "postcode" => "Asas",
                     "city" => "Asas",
                     "registrationdate" => "Asasaas",
                     "time" => "Asas",
                     "addedby" => "Asaasass");
        $warr = array("indexid" => 14);
var_dump(update($arr,$warr, "contacts"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read php manuals carefully:

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

This means that all your placeholders are replaced with the last value of `$value` / `$wvalue`, because you call `execute()` after your `foreach` loops are over and `$value` / `$wvalue` holds the last iteration value.

Comment: How do I got about to fix it then? Should I use bindValue() ?

Comment: What stops you from trying?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of that code could be simplified, especially your comma/`and` handling. Why not

```
$arr_params = array();
foreach(array_keys($arr) as $key) {
    $arr_params[] = "$key=:$key";
}
$fields = implode(',', $arr_params);
```

and similarly for the `warr` stuff, just implode with `' and '` instead, then

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET $fields WHERE $where";
```

Now you don't need to duplicate code, have extra `if`, and check if you're on the last element in the loop at all.